# Download or set Heroku app config variables while running the app locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I have an app which I have downloaded from GitHub and after pushing it to Heroku it works perfectly fine. however when I use the `heroku local` command to run it locally it throws an error regarding configuration variables missing.

How can I download these config files to my local folder (do I even need to)? Do I need to create an `.env` file manually in order to make it work?

Here is the app:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Provider = require('oidc-provider');

assert(process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME, 'process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME missing');
assert(process.env.PORT, 'process.env.PORT missing');
assert(process.env.SECURE_KEY, 'process.env.SECURE_KEY missing, run `heroku addons:create securekey`');
assert.equal(process.env.SECURE_KEY.split(',').length, 2, 'process.env.SECURE_KEY format invalid');

// new Provider instance with no extra configuration, will run in default, just needs the issuer
// identifier, uses data from runtime-dyno-metadata heroku here
const oidc = new Provider(`https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com`, {
  clients: [
    {
      client_id: 'foo',
      redirect_uris: ['https://jwt.io'], // using jwt.io as redirect_uri to show the ID Token contents
      response_types: ['id_token'],
      grant_types: ['implicit'],
      token_endpoint_auth_method: 'none',
    },
  ],
  cookies: {
    keys: process.env.SECURE_KEY.split(','),
  },
});

// Heroku has a proxy in front that terminates ssl, you should trust the proxy.
oidc.proxy = true;

// listen on the heroku generated port
oidc.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

and here is the error I get when I run "heroku local":

```
3:44:57 AM web.1 |  assert.js:383
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      throw err;
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      ^
3:44:57 AM web.1 |  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME missing
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hmffa\Desktop\my-provider\src\index.js:4:1)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
3:44:57 AM web.1 |      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
3:44:57 AM web.1 |    generatedMessage: false,
3:44:57 AM web.1 |    code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
3:44:57 AM web.1 |    actual: undefined,
3:44:57 AM web.1 |    expected: true,
3:44:57 AM web.1 |    operator: '=='
3:44:57 AM web.1 |  }
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
3:44:57 AM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables often vary between environments. Some things, like your database connection string and security keys, *should* be different locally and in production.

However, Heroku [documents an easy way to copy a config var from Heroku to a local `.env` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file):

> Sometimes you may want to use the same config var in both local and Heroku environments. For each config var that you want to add to your `.env` file, use the following command:
>
> ```
> heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s  >> .env
> ```
>
> Do not commit the `.env` file to source control. It should only be used for local configuration. Update your `.gitignore` file to exclude the `.env` file.

Note that `.env` files aren't magic. Node.js won't use the values in there out of the box.

If you [use `heroku local` to run your app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-start-your-app-locally) (as you appear to be) you should find that your `.env` file gets used. If you run it another way, you may need to do additional work, e.g. perhaps by adding [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer. Actually after adding config vars to ".env" file using the command you mentioned Heroku did not read the inputs properly. I found out that it created  .env file using UTF-16 LE encoding. I changed it to UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: Hrm, that's weird. I wonder if it has something to do with your shell? Or did the `.env` file already exist? In any case, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: I use Windows PowerShell and not Linux operating system. Maybe that is causing the problem. No I did not have `.env` file